# MacTex.pkg says it "installed successfully", but nothing has been installed

Tags: macos, installation, latex

I'm using macOS Monterey v12.5.1 with the M1 chip.

I'm trying to install MacTeX (https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html), i.e. MacTeX.pkg, but all I get is the message that the package installed successfully without anything actually being installed.

I reran the installation using

```
sudo installer -dumplog -pkg MacTeX.pkg -target / > install.log 2>&1
```

and got the following log:

```
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Debug>: Product archive /Users/bm/MacTeX.pkg trustLevel=350
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Debug>: External component packages (4) trustLevel=350
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Debug>: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: location = file://localhost
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Debug>: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Users/bm/MacTeX.pkg#Ghostscript-9.55-Start.pkg
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Debug>: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Users/bm/MacTeX.pkg#GUI-Applications-Start.pkg
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Debug>: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Users/bm/MacTeX.pkg#TeXLive-2022-Start.pkg
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Info>: Set authorization level to root for session
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Info>: Authorization is being checked, waiting until authorization arrives.
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Info>: Administrator authorization granted.
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Info>: Packages have been authorized for installation.
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Debug>: Will use PK session
Oct  3 16:14:13  installer[6531] <Debug>: Using authorization level of root for IFPKInstallElement
Oct  3 16:14:16  installer[6531] <Info>: Starting installation:
Oct  3 16:14:16  installer[6531] <Notice>: Configuring volume "Macintosh HD"
Oct  3 16:14:16  installer[6531] <Info>: Preparing disk for local booted install.
Oct  3 16:14:16  installer[6531] <Notice>: Free space on "Macintosh HD": 1.74 TB (1739772063744 bytes).
Oct  3 16:14:16  installer[6531] <Notice>: Create temporary directory "/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T//Install.6531hWCxs8"
Oct  3 16:14:16  installer[6531] <Notice>: IFPKInstallElement (3 packages)
Oct  3 16:14:16  installer[6531] <Info>: Current Path: /usr/sbin/installer
Oct  3 16:14:16  installer[6531] <Info>: Current Path: /usr/bin/sudo
Oct  3 16:14:16  installer[6531] <Notice>: PackageKit: Enqueuing install with framework-specified quality of service (utility)
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app/Contents/Library/Applications/LaTeXiT%20Helper.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “LaTeXiT Helper.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app/Contents/Library/Applications/LaTeXiT%20Helper.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app/Contents/Library/Applications/LaTeXiT Helper.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309de90 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/TeX%20Live%20Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/TLUNotifier.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “TLUNotifier.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/TeX%20Live%20Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/TLUNotifier.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/TLUNotifier.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309b0f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “LaTeXiT.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309de90 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Autoupdate.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309e0d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/TeX%20Live%20Utility.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “TeX Live Utility.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/TeX%20Live%20Utility.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309b0f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/TeX%20Live%20Utility.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Autoupdate.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/TeX%20Live%20Utility.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309de90 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “TeXShop.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309b0f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/BibDesk.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Autoupdate.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/BibDesk.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/BibDesk.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309d8c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/TeX%20Live%20Utility.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Python.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/TeX%20Live%20Utility.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309f090 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Autoupdate.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309d8c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/Resources/ScriptRunner.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “ScriptRunner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/Resources/ScriptRunner.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/Resources/ScriptRunner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309f090 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Info>: Error getting application status info for file:///Applications/TeX/BibDesk.app: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “BibDesk.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Applications/TeX/BibDesk.app, NSFilePath=/Applications/TeX/BibDesk.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000309f090 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>: Running install actions
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>: Removing temporary directory "/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T//Install.6531hWCxs8"
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>: Finalize disk "Macintosh HD"
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>: Notifying system of updated components
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>: 
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>: **** Summary Information ****
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>:   Operation      Elapsed time
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>: -----------------------------
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>:        disk      0.02 seconds
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>:      script      0.00 seconds
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>:        zero      0.00 seconds
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>:     install      13.11 seconds
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>:     -total-      13.13 seconds
Oct  3 16:14:29  installer[6531] <Notice>: 
installer: Package name is MacTeX
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade was successful.
```

I'm having the same problem with BasicTeX.pkg. No idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Chromium browsers corrupt the `MacTeX.pkg`-file during the download, which is a known problem: https://www.tug.org/mactex/faq/faq.html#qm01

I redownloaded the file through Safari and now the install works.